# Unable to retain location when switching cesium view

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am new to Cesium and I want to switch views while retaining the exact position. Initially my viewer is set to 3D. When I switch from 3D to 2D it works fine and I maintain the exact location. However when I switch from 3D to Columbus view I lose the exact location and the same happens when I switch back to 3D or from 2D to 3D the location is lost. I want to know how to switch between views while preserving the current location.